# Class Property doesn't get transpiled

Tags: typescript

I got a class property that is undefined because it is not transpiled into js:

Typescript code:

```
import * as _ from "lodash"

/**
 * User
 */
class User {

    public properties: {
        gender: string
        name: string
        first_name: string
        last_name: string
        email: string
        fb_id: string
    }

    constructor( data ) {

        _.forOwn( data, ( value: string, key: string ) => // Needs fat arrow to bind 'this'
        {
            if ( value ) { this.properties[ key ] = value }
        })

    }

    public useProperties() {
        return this.properties
    }
}

export default User
```

Transpiled code:

```
"use strict";
var _ = require("lodash");
var User = (function () {
    function User(data) {
        var _this = this;
        _.forOwn(data, function (value, key) {
            if (value) {
                _this.properties[key] = value;
            }
        });
    }
    User.prototype.useProperties = function () {
        return this.properties;
    };
    return User;
}());
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = User;
//# sourceMappingURL=user_model.js.map
```

You can see that the object 'properties' doesn't get transpiled thus the loop cannot work. Why is that and how to force proper transpilation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the object yourself if you want it to be not `undefined`:

```
class User {

    public properties: {
        gender: string
        name: string
        first_name: string
        last_name: string
        email: string
        fb_id: string
    } = <any> { };
```

TypeScript doesn't guess about which class properties you want to be initialized and which you don't.

Comment: Thanks, how would you replace <any> with an 'as' syntax ?

Comment: @RobertBrax `= { } as any;`